# sort record by number in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

sort record by number in firestore

How can I make the record sort in ascending order by number?

this is my code

```
getPosts() {
 this.firestoreService.getCollection<Post>(this.path).subscribe(  res => {
        this.posts = res;
 });
}
```

Comment: What number are you referring to? Like a field in document?

Comment: if it is a document field, I want to order it according to the number that it has in ascending order, I have it in firestore

Comment: have you checked these methods - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data ?
I suppose that angular firestore module might have some syntactic differences